# How do I groupBy on a SchemaRDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have a SchemaRDD tableRDD. How can i groupBy on a certain column and get the `count(*) as countGrouped` of the resultant set.

I am trying something like :

`tableRDD.groupBy('colname)(??).collect()`

I am not able to understand what should be my aggregate function (represented by `??`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of a non-column like `*`, you simply put it in quotes. So, your query would look like this:

```
tableRDD.groupBy('colname)(count("*") as 'countGrouped).collect()
```